# NoneType Error when trying to parse Table using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here's my code:

```
source = urllib.request.urlopen('http://nflcombineresults.com/nflcombinedata_expanded.php ?year=2015&pos=&college=').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

table = soup.table
table = soup.find(id='datatable')
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
#print(table_rows)

year = []
name = []
college = []
pos = []
height = []
weight = []
hand_size = []
arm_length = []
wonderlic = []
fortyyrd = []

for row in table_rows[1:]:
    col = row.find_all('td')
    #row = [i.text for i in td]
    #print(col[4])

    # Create a variable of the string inside each <td> tag pair,
    column_1 = col[0].string.strip()
    # and append it to each variable
    year.append(column_1)

    column_2 = col[1].string.strip()
    name.append(column_2)

    column_3 = col[2].string.strip()
    college.append(column_3)

    column_4 = col[3].string.strip()
    pos.append(column_4)

    #print(col[4])
    column_5 = col[4].string.strip()
    height.append(column_5)
```

There are several more columns in the table I want to add, but whenever I try and run these last two lines, I get an error saying:

> "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'"

when I print col[4] right above this line, I get:

```
<td><div align="center">69</div></td>
```

I originally thought this is due to missing data, but the first instance of missing data in the original table on the website is in the 9th column (Wonderlic) of the first row, not the 4th column.

There are several other columns not included in this snippet of code that I want to add to my dataframe and I'm getting the NoneType error with them as well despite there being an entry in that cell.

I'm fairly new to parsing tables from a site using BeautifulSoup and so this could be a stupid question, but why is this object NoneType how can I fix this so I can put this table into a pandas dataframe?

Comment: is the site generating dynamically JavasScript? Can you give the url used?

Comment: Here's the url used, http://nflcombineresults.com/nflcombinedata_expanded.php?year=2015&pos=&college=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

The actual error is happening on the last row of the table which has a single cell, here is it's HTML:

```
<tr style="background-color:#333333;"><td colspan="15">&nbsp;</td></tr>
```

Just *slice it*:

```
for row in table_rows[1:-1]:
```

As far as improving the overall quality of the code, you can/should follow @宏杰李's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Alternately if you want to try it with pandas, you can do it like so:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html("http://nflcombineresults.com/nflcombinedata_expanded.php?year=2015&pos=&college=")[0]
df.head()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: yea i tried doing it with pandas but I kept getting an error saying: TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U1') dtype('<U1') dtype('<U1'). Regardless, I've managed to get it into a Pandas df with the assistance of the other answers. Thanks for your help!

Comment: So glad I found this. I've been attempting the same with the exact same site...same error with Pandas. Wish it worked as it's just much more compact. But I'll give BeautifulSoup a go. Was trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

r = requests.get('http://nflcombineresults.com/nflcombinedata_expanded.php?year=2015&pos=&college=')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
for tr in soup.table.find_all('tr'):
    row = [td.text for td in tr.find_all('td')]
    print (row)
```

out:

```
['Year', 'Name', 'College', 'POS', 'Height (in)', 'Weight (lbs)', 'Hand Size (in)', 'Arm Length (in)', 'Wonderlic', '40 Yard', 'Bench Press', 'Vert Leap (in)', 'Broad Jump (in)', 'Shuttle', '3Cone', '60Yd Shuttle']
['2015', 'Ameer Abdullah', 'Nebraska', 'RB', '69', '205', '8.63', '30.00', '', '4.60', '24', '42.5', '130', '3.95', '6.79', '11.18']
['2015', 'Nelson Agholor', 'Southern California', 'WR', '73', '198', '9.25', '32.25', '', '4.42', '12', '', '', '', '', '']
['2015', 'Malcolm Agnew', 'Southern Illinois', 'RB', '70', '202', '', '', '', '*4.59', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['2015', 'Jay Ajayi', 'Boise State', 'RB', '73', '221', '10.00', '32.00', '24', '4.57', '19', '39.0', '121', '4.10', '7.10', '11.10']
['2015', 'Brandon Alexander', 'Central Florida', 'FS', '74', '195', '', '', '', '*4.59', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['2015', 'Kwon Alexander', 'Louisiana State', 'OLB', '73', '227', '9.25', '30.25', '', '4.55', '24', '36.0', '121', '4.20', '7.14', '']
['2015', 'Mario Alford', 'West Virginia', 'WR', '68', '180', '9.38', '31.25', '', '4.43', '13', '34.0', '121', '4.07', '6.64', '11.22']
['2015', 'Detric Allen', 'East Carolina', 'CB', '73', '200', '', '', '', '*4.59', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['2015', 'Javorius Allen', 'Southern California', 'RB', '73', '221', '9.38', '31.75', '12', '4.53', '11', '35.5', '121', '4.28', '6.96', '']
```

As you can see, there are a lot of empty fields in the table, the better way is to put all the field in a list, then unpack them or use namedtuple.
This will improve your code stability.

Comment: [Code-only answers are generally low-quality](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/219368). Please consider improving your answer(s) adding explanations, links to the documentation, points why the OP should be approaching it this way and not the other. Thanks.